# Get user detail in after user login TWITTER

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, twitter

Hi how do you get user Details ID,Name,Screen Name ETC after user has logged using your application

For Example user has entered login details and after it has entered these details i want to get the Details in josn at run time and store it in to DATABASE

i am using Abraham Auth

```
https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth example
```

my INDEX.PHP

```
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
    header('Location: ./clearsession.php');
}
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

please i have been searching for so much time i just need to perform a simple action

THANK YOU

Comment: Look at the examples in the repository and also check out the actual twitter api for the end points that you need to call. Something like `//$connection->get('users/show', array('screen_name' => 'abraham'));` as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply extract the properties of `content` object, then store them into an array before adding them to the DB:

```
$arr=array();


$arr["screen_name"]= $content->screen_name;
$arr["id"]= $content->id;
```

Eventually you will obtain a simple array `$arr` to store it to its final destination

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter-OAuth library you are using is simple an oAuth wrapper for the basic Twitter API v1.1. The script handles the authentication (which you are already using) and lets you use all the standard calls implemented in the Twitter REST API v1.1.

See the [documentation here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) and try the command you want like this:

```
$content = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline',$parameters); // GET
$content = $connection->put('account/update_profile',$parameters); // POST
```

On the twitter dev-page everything is very well documented!